Next.JS permissions issues in Docker Compose
I am setting up Docker by referring to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-compose.
I am implementing an upload method that saves a file in the public/uploads folder of the server and reads it via the Get method.
The dev.Dockerfile version works correctly,
but with the prod.Dockerfile, the upload works fine, but the ‘GET’ method returns a 404 error, possibly due to a permissions issue.
Could you provide a solution?
docker-compose.prod.yml
version: "3"

services:
  next-app:
    container_name: next-app
    build:
      context: ./next-app
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
      args:
        ENV_VARIABLE: ${ENV_VARIABLE}
        NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - photos-web
    env_file:
      - ./next-app/.env.local
    volumes:
      - uploads:/app/public/uploads

  # Add more containers below (nginx, postgres, etc.)

# Define a network, which allows containers to communicate
# with each other, by using their container name as a hostname
networks:
  photos-web:
    external: true

volumes:
  uploads:

prod.Dockerfile
# FROM node:18-bullseye AS base
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install Perl
RUN apk add --no-cache perl
# RUN apt update
# RUN apt install perl

# Step 1. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
# Omit --production flag for TypeScript devDependencies
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i; \
  # Allow install without lockfile, so example works even without Node.js installed locally
  else echo "Warning: Lockfile not found. It is recommended to commit lockfiles to version control." && yarn install; \
  fi

COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY next.config.js .
COPY tsconfig.json .
RUN mkdir -p /app/public/uploads

# Environment variables must be present at build time
# https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14030
ARG ENV_VARIABLE
ENV ENV_VARIABLE=${ENV_VARIABLE}
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE=${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage. Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line to disable telemetry at build time
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# Build Next.js based on the preferred package manager
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then pnpm build; \
  else npm run build; \
  fi

# Note: It is not necessary to add an intermediate step that does a full copy of `node_modules` here

# Step 2. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner

WORKDIR /app

# Install Perl
# RUN apk add --no-cache perl

# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

RUN mkdir -p /app/public/uploads && chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/public/uploads && chmod g+s /app/public/uploads

USER nextjs

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/public ./public
# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/node_modules/exiftool-vendored.pl ./node_modules/exiftool-vendored.pl

# Environment variables must be redefined at run time
ARG ENV_VARIABLE
ENV ENV_VARIABLE=${ENV_VARIABLE}
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE=${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}

# Uncomment the following line to disable telemetry at run time
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# Note: Don't expose ports here, Compose will handle that for us

CMD ["node", "server.js"]


dev version that works normally
docker-compose.dev.yml
version: "3"

services:
  next-app:
    container_name: next-app
    build:
      context: ./next-app
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile

    # Set environment variables directly in the docker-compose file
    environment:
      ENV_VARIABLE: ${ENV_VARIABLE}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VARIABLE}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
        - photos-web
    # Set environment variables based on the .env file
    env_file:
      - .env
      - ./next-app/.env.local
    volumes:
      - ./next-app/src:/app/src
      - uploads:/app/public/uploads

  # Add more containers below (nginx, postgres, etc.)

# Define a network, which allows containers to communicate
# with each other, by using their container name as a hostname
networks:
  photos-web:
    external: true

volumes:
  uploads:

dev.Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache perl

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i; \
  # Allow install without lockfile, so example works even without Node.js installed locally
  else echo "Warning: Lockfile not found. It is recommended to commit lockfiles to version control." && yarn install; \
  fi

COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY next.config.js .
COPY tsconfig.json .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage. Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line to disable telemetry at run time
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# Note: Don't expose ports here, Compose will handle that for us

# Start Next.js in development mode based on the preferred package manager
CMD \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn dev; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run dev; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then pnpm dev; \
  else npm run dev; \
  fi

